# What are those variables in Cochran's formula

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, mathematical-statistics

I cannot find any information about the Cochran's formula below:

$$\text{Sample Size} = \frac{n}{1 + (n/\text{population})}$$ in which $n$ is equal to $Z * Z [P (1-P)/(D*D)]$

So I assume Z is the z-score but what is P and what is D? I have read that CL is 95% and maring of error 5%, what if I want the CL to be 99% - will I simply use the proper z-score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P is the probability, leave 50% for the most conservative assumption. D is the margin of error. To get different CL, just use the associated z score.